# How can I get the nullvalue of a datagridview buttoncolumn?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Is it possible to get the nullvalue of a datagridview button column when click and change the background color and change back to default color when the other button in the column is check 
`dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "johndoe";`

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1[e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
```